# RDS PostgreSQL major version upgrade issue

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, major-upgrade

I have an RDS instance with PostgreSQL version 13.13. The goal is to upgrade it to version 15.5. During upgrade, I am getting an error

```
5342: GRANT "" TO "my_user_1" GRANTED BY "my_user_1";
5343: psql:/rdsdbdata/db/pg_upgrade_output.d/20240315T142926.905/dump/pg_upgrade_dump_globals.sql:186: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
5344: LINE 1: GRANT "" TO "my_user_1" GRANTED BY "my_user_1";
```

So anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: well it's a bit hard to understand what went wrong, just looking at the shown code, you are trying to grant the value of a zero-length variable, so unless there is no other logic you need to provide the other part of the code that affects this. If that is indeed separate logic then you just need to provide a proper role/[Set of] permission/s. But this statement is illegal in both PSQL-13 and 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how and why this happened, but somehow role with the empty name was created on my DB. Other copies of that DB didn't have that empty role. I was unable to delete that empty role because it was empty. I also was unable to modify it.
In general update from 13.13 to 15.5 is happening very with no problems.